# AS400 jdbc character conversion

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

using jdbc (jt400) to insert data into an as400 table.
db table code page is 424. [Host Code Page 424](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pcomhelp/v5r9/topic/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/reference/pdf/hcp_referenceV58.pdf)

the ebcdic 424 code page does not support many of the characters that may come from the client.
for example the sign `→` (Ascii 26 Hex 1A)

the result is an incorrect translation.

is there any built-in way in the toolbox to remove any of the unsupported characters?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a logical file over your ccsid424 physical file with a different codepage. It is possible on the as/400 to create logical files with different codepages for individual columns, by adding the keyword `CCSID(<num>)`. You can even set it to an unicode charset, e.g. `CCSID(1200)` for UTF-16. Of course your physical file will still only be able to store chars that are in the 424 codepage, and those will be replaced by some invalid character char, but the translation might be better that way.

There is no way to store chars, that are not in codepage 424 in a column with that codepage directly (the only way I can think of is encoding them somehow with multiple chars, but that is most likely *not* what you want to do, since it will bring more problems than it "solves").

If you have control over that system, and it is possible to do some bigger changes, you could do it the other way around: create a new unicode version of that physical file with a different name (I'd propose CCSID(1200), that's as close as you get to UTF-16 on as/400 afaik, and UTF-8 is not supported by all parts of the system in my experience. IBM does recommend 1200 for unicode). Than transfer all data from your old file to the new one, delete the old one (before that, **backup it!**), and than create a logical file over the new physical, with the name of the old physical file. In that logical file change all ccsid-bearing columns from 1200 to 424. That way, existing programs can still work on the data. Of course there will be invalid chars in the logical file now, once you insert data that is not in a subset of ccsid 424; so you will most likely have to take a look at all programs that use the new logical file.